# Expressão regular para detectar a bandeira do cartão de crédito

Tags: regex

Eu preciso do Regex para detectar quando a bandeira do cartão de crédito é Hipercard, Aura e Elo.

Eu já possuo regexes para Amex, Martercard, Diners Club, Visa, Discover and JCB:

```
Visa: ^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})
Mastercard: ^5[1-5][0-9]{14}
Amex: ^3[47][0-9]{13}
Diners Club: ^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}
Discover: ^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}
JCB: ^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}
```

Comment: Existe um serviço gratuito que retorna essa informação. Veja em http://www.binlist.net/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Os números de cartão de crédito seguem um padrão internacional chamado [IEC-7812](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7812).

Basicamente, os seis primeiros dígitos do cartão são o Issuer identifier number (IIN) (Número de Identificação do Emissor).

Então, você não precisa de um regex, mas de uma lista de IIN com a qual pode checar o número.

Comment: Acho que o `regex` que ele quis falar foi a regra para utilizar o IIN.

Answer (score 31):

A quem interessar, segue uma lista de BINs:

```
| Bandeira   | Comeca com                                  | Máximo de número | Máximo de número cvc |
| ---------- | ------------------------------------------- | ---------------- | -------------------- |
| Visa       | 4                                           | 13,16            | 3                    |
| Mastercard | 5                                           | 16               | 3                    |
| Diners     | 301,305,36,38                               | 14,16            | 3                    |
| Elo        | 636368,438935,504175,451416,509048,509067,  |                  | 3(?)
|            | 509049,509069,509050,509074,509068,509040,
|            | 509045,509051,509046,509066,509047,509042,
|            | 509052,509043,509064,509040                 |                  |                      
|            | 36297, 5067,4576,4011                       | 16               | 3
| Amex       | 34,37                                       | 15               | 4                    |
| Discover   | 6011,622,64,65                              | 16               | 4                    |
| Aura       | 50                                          | 16               | 3                    |
| jcb        | 35                                          | 16               | 3                    |
| Hipercard  | 38,60                                       | 13,16,19         | 3                    |
```

https://gist.github.com/erikhenrique/5931368

Comment: a sua lista de números do Elo não bate com a do link, nem das revisões anteriores do mesmo. Algum motivo? Você tem outra fonte desses BIN?

Comment: Opa igor, essa lista ELO eu atualizei após receber um e-mail do moip com os novos Bins da Elo. Abcs

Answer (score 21):

Elo:

```
/^((((636368)|(438935)|(504175)|(451416)|(636297))\d{0,10})|((5067)|(4576)|(4011))\d{0,12})$/
```

Hipercard:

```
/^(606282\d{10}(\d{3})?)|(3841\d{15})$/
```

Answer (score 12):

HiperCard:

```
/^(606282\d{10}(\d{3})?)|(3841\d{15})$/
```

Answer (score 4):

Pra quem trabalha com tecnologias baseadas em `nodejs` e queiram um jeito mais simples que aborda uma grande quantidade de cartões recomendo utilizar o `npm` [Credit Card Type](https://github.com/braintree/credit-card-type) para identificar qual a bandeira do cartão através do seu número.

Uso ES6 modulos:

```
import creditCardType from 'credit-card-type'


creditCardType(cardNumber).filter((card) => {
  return card.type
})
```

Carões suportados:

- visa
- mastercard
- american-express
- diners-club
- discover
- jcb
- unionpay
- maestro
- mir
- elo
- hiper
- hipercard