# Validar cartão de credito com js

Tags: javascript, regex

Gostaria de saber a forma de validar o cartão de credito através do Js.

Visa começa com 4
Mastercard começa com 51, 52, 53, 54 ou 55;
American Express começa com 34 e 37

Alguém sabe a melhor forma de validar isso?

```html
<fieldset class="fsResDir">
    <legend>Dados do Cartão&nbsp;</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="RadBand" id="visa" checked />
    <label for="visa">
      <img src="visa.png" />
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadBand" id="mast" />
    <label for="mast">
      <img src="master.png" />
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadBand" id="amex" />
    <label for="amex">
      <img src="amex.png" />
    </label>
    <label for="val" class="lab90">Validade:</label>
    <input type="text" class="ent20Form" id="val" name="TxtValMes" />/
    <input type="text" class="ent40Form" name="TxtValAno" />
    <label for="num" class="lab90">Numero:</label>
    <input type=text class="ent120Form" id="num" name="TxtNumero" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: [Expressão regular para detectar a bandeira do cartão de crédito](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3715/91)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
var cartoes = {
    Visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})/,
    Mastercard: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}/,
    Amex: /^3[47][0-9]{13}/,
    DinersClub: /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}/,
    Discover: /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}/,
    JCB: /^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}/
};

function testarCC(nr, cartoes) {
    for (var cartao in cartoes) if (nr.match(cartoes[cartao])) return cartao;
    return false;
}

var valido = '4444555566667777';
var invalido = '1234567890';

[valido, invalido].forEach(function(teste){
   console.log(testarCC(teste, cartoes)); 
});

// dá VISA, false
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdLL7qy2/

A ideia dessa função é percorrer as regex de cada cartão e retornar o nome do cartão, ou false caso nenhum padrão seja válido.

Comment: Entendi, seria possível ele marcar automaticamente um radiobox relacionado a bandeira do cartão. Ao invés de validar?

Comment: @ygorbr sim. Qual é o HTML nesse caso?

Comment: Editei o post com o codigo em html

Comment: @ygorbr é isto que procuras? http://jsfiddle.net/tdq8os3d/

Comment: Sim, mas acho que to precisando de um reparos. Mas a base acredito que seja essa msm. A ideia é ele mudar automaticamente assim que um numero é digitado. Obrigado meu amigo

Comment: Me ajudou muito