# Validar inputs em formulário com expressões regulares

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Eu tenho campo de Contatos na page onde o usuário deve preencher, por exemplo, o nome, ele deveria apenas digitar letras, no campo telefone, apenas números e email obrigatório o uso do "@". A ideia é exibir uma mensagem para o usuário quando ele inserir número no campo "nome" e assim por diante.

Eu consegui capturar o input do usuário, mas a expressão regular não funciona.

Este é meu código:

```
var validaNome = $("#input-nome");
validaNome.on("input", function(){
    var digitado = validaNome.val();
    var comparavel = new RegExp("ab+c");

    if(digitado <= comparavel){
        $(".digite-nome").css("display", "none");
    }else {
        $(".digite-nome").css("display", "block");
    };
});
```

A variável comparável recebe a expressão regular e então usa-la na validação.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Ou existe outra forma de validar isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma outra [resposta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94489/129) mas para cartões de crédito. A ideia interessante lá é a organização de código, que facilita a leitura e desenvolvimento.

Poderias fazer isso assim:

```js
var inputs = {
  nome: /^[\w\s]+$/,
  telefone: /^[\d\s]+$/,
  email: /^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/
};


$("form input").on("change", function() {
  var tipo = this.name;
  var regex = inputs[tipo];

  if (this.value.match(regex)) alert('O campo ' + tipo + ' está válido!');
  else alert('O campo ' + tipo + ' está inválido!')
});
```

Comment: INCRIVEL!
INCRIVEL!

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para validar o nome você pode utilizar este regex:

```
/^[\p{L}\s]+$
```

Para o telefone

```
/(\d{3}|\d{2}|\(\d{2}\))\s*(\d{9}|\d{8})
```

E para email

```
/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
```

Comment: Não funciona, porque o navegador parece interpretar a variável como uma string...

Comment: Quando adicionar o console.log dentro do IF e do ELSE, consigo ver os inputs do usuário comparando com a variável.
Ele só da "Okay" se eu digitar /^[\p{L}\s]+$. não lê como uma expressão regular.