# Expressão regular para detectar a bandeira do cartão de crédito quando houver caracteres específicos no número

Tags: regex

Estou precisando criar uma expressão regular (Regex) que consiga identificar o numero do cartão mesmo quando houver caracteres específicos entre os números,

**Exemplo:**
Regex atual:  `((\d{16}|\d{4}(.\d{4}){3})|(\d{4}(\d{4}){3}))`
Que me permite ler o número dos cartões quando colocados da seguinte formas:

> 4012001037141112
>   4012 0010 3714 1112
>   4012/0010/3714/1112
>   4012.0010.3714.1112
>   4012*0010*3714*1112

Porém preciso criar um regex que identifique o numero do cartão, sem olhar em qual campo o carácter especifico esta digitado, alguns exemplos de como poderia aparecer o numero do cartão e que o regex acima não identifica:

> 4/0/1/2/0/0/1/0/3/7/1/4/1/1/1/2
>     4.0.1.2.0.0.1.0.3.7.1.4.1.1.1.2
>     4.0.12001037141112
>     401200103714/1112
>     401*200103714111*2

O regex que tenho hoje funciona apenas quando o carácter é digitado depois da 4 casa, quero que ele tenha a mesma ação independente de onde estiver o carácter especifico.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Essas **configurações** irei usa **no DLP**, eu **não tenho acesso a parte de programação** dele, só a um campo onde coloco a expressão regular.

Comment: Sanitize a string para ter somente números e validar normalmente. O que está pretendendo não tem sentido lógico.

Comment: [Expressão regular para detectar a bandeira do cartão de crédito](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3715/91)

Comment: Em que linguagem queres fazer isso? Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94489/129

Comment: Daniel eu ja tenho essas expressões regulares configuradas em minha ferramenta, porem se existir um usuario um pouco mais esperto ele consegue burlar a ferramenta, pois essas expressões que você passo só pega a informação se o numero do cartão for digitado sem nenhum carácter entre os números, e como trabalhamos para manter a segurança da informação , se não criar uma dessa maneira, teremos vazamento de muitos números de cartões de credito na empresa, estou tentando afunilar o máximo possível o meu filtro..

Answer (score 1):

Tente essa expressão:

```
((\d{16}|(.?\d){16})|(\d{4}(\d{4}){3}))
```

Caso queira que aceita mais de um caractere específico entre os números pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```
([^0-9]*\d{1}){16}
```

Caso queira incorporar no regex da questão (não acho necessário, mas fica a seu critério):

```
((\d{16}|[^0-9]*\d{1}){16}|(\d{4}(\d{4}){3}))
```

Comment: Samir....Sua expressão resolve meu problema, uma pergunta, testei ela e esta ok, porem se eu digitar o numero colocando 2 caractres ou mais entre os numeros ele nao reconhece, EX: 40//12001037141112, consigo fazer algum ajuste para ela continuar pegando o numero independente do numero de caracters digitados entre os numeros?

Comment: @MarcusSouza , olhe a edição da resposta.

Comment: Samir quando usei a expressao ((\d{16}|[^0-9]*\d{1}){16}|(\d{4}(\d{4}){3})),  ela funciona exatamente como eu precisava... Só nao reconhece os numeros de cartões das bandeiras Americacan Express e Dinners Club. Se tiver alguma dica agradeço. Caso não tenha Ja ajudou a resolver meu problema 99%.....Muito obrigado

Comment: @MarcusSouza, se refere a quantidade de números?

Comment: Caso seja, pode colocar esta expressão: `(\d{14,16}|([^0-9]*\d{1}){14,16}|(\d{4}(\d{4}){3}))` que aceita de 14 a 16 números. Ou deseja outro intervalo?

Comment: Samir desculpa a demora, estva sem acesso a Internet, vou estar validando essa nova expressao e respondo assim que testar..Obrigado

Comment: Bom dia Samir, deu certo, Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus, para validar o número do cartão de crédito, eu uso o Algoritmo Luhn. Segue a classe:

```
public static class Luhn
{
    public static bool LuhnCheck(this string cardNumber)
    {
        return LuhnCheck(cardNumber.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray());
    }

    private static bool LuhnCheck(this int[] digits)
    {
        return GetCheckValue(digits) == 0;
    }

    private static int GetCheckValue(int[] digits)
    {
        return digits.Select((d, i) => i % 2 == digits.Length % 2 ? ((2 * d) % 10) + d / 5 : d).Sum() % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: o Marcus não tem acesso ao código fonte.